# Codeigniter HMVC does not clear form fields

Tags: php, ajax, post, hmvc, codeigniter-form-helper

I am developing a site with CI 2.1.3

I have a blog module, in this blog I have a form to post a comment.

I am calling this form inside a view with:

```
echo Modules:: run('blog/comment');
```

When I submit this form with ajaxForm, the values of the input fields are not being cleared.

My controller’s function for the comment form:

```
    public function comment($postId)
{
 $this->load->helper('form');
 $this->data['success'] = FALSE;
 $this->data['postId'] = $postId;

 if(!isset($_POST['comment_submit']))
 {     
   $this->data['new_comment'] = $this->blog_comment_m->get_new();
 }
 else
 {
  $this->data['new_comment'] = $this->blog_comment_m->object_from_post(array('author', 'authur_email', 'content'));
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $rules = $this->blog_comment_m->rules;
  $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

  if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
  {
    $this->data['success'] = TRUE;
        $this->data['new_comment'] = $this->blog_comment_m->get_new();
  }
 }

 $this->load->view('add_comment', $this->data);
}
```

The comment form:

```
<div id="commentAjax">
<?php $attr = array('id'=>'commentForm'); echo form_open(site_url('blog/comment/' . 

$postId), $attr); ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $postId; ?>" />
  <div style="border-top:2px groove #930"><h4>Leave a Comment</h4></div>

  <div class="control-group <?php if(form_error('author')) echo 'error'; ?>">
    <label>Name *</label>
    <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'author', 'class'=>'input-large', 'value'=>set_value('author', $new_comment->author))); ?>
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('author'); ?></span>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group <?php if(form_error('author_email')) echo 'error'; ?>">
    <label>Email *</label>
    <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'author_email', 'class'=>'input-large', 'value'=>set_value('author_email', $new_comment->author_email))); ?>
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('author_email'); ?></span>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group <?php if(form_error('content')) echo 'error'; ?>">
    <label>Comment *</label>
    <?php echo form_textarea(array('name'=>'content', 'value'=>set_value('content', $new_comment->content))); ?>
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('content'); ?></span>
  </div>
   <div>
        <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Send Comment', 'class="btn btn-submit"');?>
      <input type="hidden" name="comment_submit" value="1" />
  </div>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>

    <?php if($success): ?>
    <div style="border:1px solid #666; background:#9F9; color:#000; margin-top:10px; width:50%; padding:5px; font-weight:bold">
      <p>Thank you for your comment.</p>
      <p>To avoid spam, your comment has been submitted for approval.</p>
      <p><h2 class="highland">Highland Coffee Roastery</h2></p>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<script>
$(function()
{                        
    var options = { target: '#commentAjax' };
    $('#commentForm').ajaxForm(options);
});
</script>
```

I dumped the $new_comment array and the fields values are empty.

I checked the page source and the input fields values = ''.

Yet, I still see the values that I submitted in the input fields.

Refreshing the page, still, displays the values.

What is wrong?

Comment: By the way, is there a way to get an email when someone answer my question? Can't find this option anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on the Daniweb forum:

Ok, the problem is that set_value() doesn’t consider if the validation runs true or false, usually you redirect() and so the POST array is resetted automatically, here we can force this action by extending /system/libraries/Form_validation.php, create /application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php and paste this:

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class My_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    }
    public function resetpostdata()
    {
    $obj =& _get_validation_object();
    foreach($obj->_field_data as $key)
    {
    $this->_field_data[$key['field']]['postdata'] = NULL;
    }
    return true;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

After the validation runs true, call the method, as in this example:

```
  if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
    # . . .
    }
    else
    {
    $this->form_validation->resetpostdata();
    # load view & other stuff
    }
```